# change formatting dictionary with lists as values python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dictionary

I have a dictionary with lists as values which I'd like to export to an excel file.

My dictionary currently looks like this:

```
{1: [0, 120, 115, 100, 91, 131, 74, 14, 8, 105, 122, 47, 103, 0], 2: [0, 107, 25, 26, 121, 118], .. }
```

I would like to export this to an excel file with the following format: there should be two columns one with the keys and one with values in the lists that have that key. So for each list item you should know which key it belongs to. So for example the first column is gonna be a bunch of ones and the second column is simply 0, 120, 115, 100 etc.

I figured that I should maybe transpose this dictionary but this seems difficult because of the lists. I was also thinking to transform it to a pandas dataframe which I can then export to excel. How can I quickly change the format of my dictionary?

If I'm correct the dictionary I need should look something like this:

```
{1:0, 1:120, 1:115, 1:100, 1:91, 1:131, 1:74, 1:14, 1:8, 1:105, 1:122, 1:47, 1:103, 1:0, 2:0, 2:107..}
```

Comment: You cannot have a key more than once in a dictionary.  For your example dictionary, if you looked up key `1`, which value would you expect to get back? Try `[(k, v) for k, vals in d.items() for v in vals]` to get a list of tuples. Gives `[(1, 0), (1, 120), (1, 115), (1, 100), (1, 91), (1, 131), (1, 74), (1, 14), (1, 8), (1, 105), (1, 122), (1, 47), (1, 103), (1, 0), (2, 0), (2, 107), (2, 25), (2, 26), (2, 121), (2, 118)]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should first build a list of key,value tuples from your dictionary, then use pandas to convert it to excel.

```
d = {1: [0, 120, 115, 100, 91, 131, 74, 14, 8, 105, 122, 47, 103, 0], 2: [0, 107, 25, 26, 121, 118] } 

data = [(i, j) for i in d.keys() for j in d[i]]

# Export to excel format
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=["A", "B"])
df.to_excel("table.xlsx")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `pandas` to create a dataframe with two columns ("keys" and "values") and save it to a excel file

```
import pandas as pd

dct = {1: [0, 120, 115, 100, 91, 131, 74, 14, 8, 105, 122, 47, 103, 0], 
       2: [0, 107, 25, 26, 121, 118]}

# define the second column name as "values"
df = pd.DataFrame({'values': dct}).reset_index() 
# rename the first colum, here "keys"
df.rename(columns={"index": "keys"}, inplace = True)
# save dataframe to excel file
df.to_excel("output.xlsx")
```